# Go-to questions for visa refusal

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

Would it make sense to compile a canonical question and answer to advise people on what to do if their visa is refused?

As far as I can see there are a set of reasons which are always quoted by immigration officers such as:

- no proof of support
- no proof of accommodation
- Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided
- Your intention to leave the territory of the member states before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained
- etc.

We currently have [one such question in the queue which is flagged as a duplicate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/close/33658) of [a not-so-duplicate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy). However the answer to both would probably be the same, hence the possible need for a canonical question/answer.

What I'm thinking is a question in the form of `My visa was refused. What should I do?` and a canonical answer covering all possible visa refusal reasons. We could of course start with a regulated, and smaller, scope such as Schengen visas.

Comment: It feels like a lot of the refusals questions come from people not understanding what the vias approval people are actually asking, and people thinking it's a pure check-box process (ie is this piece of paper present, tick). Explaining that (for Schengen/UK at least) the two main questions are: Will you leave and will you try and work while here. Explaining that is what you need to prove might help people?

Comment: @CMaster It would therefore be useful to compile such a canonical question/answer.

Comment: I was agreeing with the drive of the question, sorry if not clear

Comment: This is about Schengen refusals, hopefully we are able to divert the bulk of those to existing questions.  My DREAM is to reach the same state with UK refusals. All duplicates. There is no reason for a site already 5 years old to be creating new answers for visa refusals!